# How to understand the clustered standard error from HLM perspective?

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I am an experimentalist and want to run the linear regression to control for the within-subject correlation that violates the assumption of independence. With the practice in the field of economics,normally we take the **cluster standard error** into account, see below both the *Stata* and *R* code examples that achieve exact same results. From the perspective of psychology, it prefers to emphasize the random effect of the intercepts/slopes. Here I have two questions.

1. How can I get the same or similar results as I achieved above with the **lmer** command in **lme4** package of R? I've listed the **lmer** command below but the results turn out to be different.

2. How can I explain the details to a psychologist what the clustered standard error method achieves with HLM terminology, can we understand it has already considered the random effect of the intercept of the with-subject factor Species but with the fixed slope of **X**(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length and Petal.Width)?

stata code

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/iris, clear
reg seplen sepwid petlen petwid,cluster(iris)
```

R code

```
library(lfe)
OLS1<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width |0|0|Species,data=iris)
summary(OLS1)$coe
```

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width+ (1 | Species), iris)
summary(fm1)
```